# How to force https to specific URLs and others don't?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to force https for the following two URLs:

1. http://secure.gopopal.com/paymentstep.php
2. http://secure.gopopal.com/registername.php

and all the other URLs use http.

How should I do this with .htaccess?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^secure\.gopopal\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(paymentstep|registername)\.php$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

#if needed, everything else
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule !^(paymentstep|registername)\.php$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```